# How to rotate a picture in a 1D pixel array without deformation?

Tags: java, arrays, rotation, game-engine, pixel

Actually I asked this question yesterday, but it wasn't a really explained question.

I'am working on my own game engine and I need a method what can rotate my pictures, but my mehod is really deform it like this:

[this is my mouse cursor after rotation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sruRe.png)

I need somthing like this:

[this is a picture what i need to get](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OaQsn.png) (do not care about the color difference it isn't important)

And this is the wanted code:

```
public int[] rotate(int[] pixels, int origoX, int origoY, double angle){
      int[] result;
      //get the array of pixels 
      //rotate it with angle
      /*origoX,origoY are the center of the rotation, but it really isn't                   
      important it's just comfort*/        
      return result;
}
```

I know there is the Java Graphics2D Class what can rotate pictures like this, but after the rotation I can't get back my pixel array to work with.

I believe this is a satisfying explanation. If not, please ask in the comments.

Comment: rotation in 1D? I can't only think of mirroring... or maybe you should explain how the (2D) pixels are organized in that 1D array (like every 16 values are one row or so)

Comment: this is a 1D array , every element is a color in hex: eg 0xff112233. Its placed   in the array row after row. you can get the x,y pixel like pixels[ x + y * width]